# Items disappear when turned on subdivision surface

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

did everything according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNgljHnbhA but at one point something went wrong. When I turned on the subdivision surface, then everything was gone. enter the image description here

[image]

File [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/1dc8e6d383394b70a537f9ef7355be77)

Comment: hello, at what minute of the video? Also please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi i emailed you everything

Comment: maybe you should share the link here  ;)  I'm not sure why but there's no problem for me when I open your file, I can still see your boat once Subdivision Surface activated

Comment: this is weird but thank you very much. If I have any problems, I will contact you

Comment: sure, I hope someone will understand what's the problem here though, maybe a bug, have you tried Subdivision Surface with other objects?

Comment: what happens when you disable Optimal Display in the modifier?  Also, could you add your file to your question, so that those of us who don't read @moonboots email can see it?

Comment: @Marty Fouts, I've edited his question, I hope he doesn't mind if I share his file

Comment: @moonboots, thanks.  Alas, like you I don't experience his problem.

Comment: so it's probably a bug :/